# REST works with getting all users, but fails with getting one user saying No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource

Tags: angular, spring-boot, rest, cors

I'm a bit lost here, I have two apps running, a spring-boot backend and an angular 8 front end, in the backend I have a `UserApi` thats supposed to return a `List` of users when first visiting `localhost:4200` this works fine and I get my users from the database. I do this like so

```
@CrossOrigin(origins = "http://localhost:4200")
@RestController
@RequestMapping("api/")
public class UserApi {

    @Autowired
    private UserService userService;

    @GetMapping("users")
    public List<User> getUsers() {
        return userService.findAllUsers();
    }
    }
```

in the front I have the following

```
export class UserService extends HttpConfig {

  getUsers(): Observable<User[]> {
    return this.http().get<User[]>(`${this.getBaseUrl() + "/users"}`);
  }
}
```

For `HttpConfig` that the `UserService.ts` file extends is simple and straightforward, looking like

```
export class HttpConfig {

  private baseUrl = "http://localhost:8080/api";

  constructor(private httpClient: HttpClient) { }

  getBaseUrl(){
    return this.baseUrl;
  }

  http(){
    return this.httpClient;
  }
}
```

But as soon as I want to send some parameters through, I get the following on the browser

```
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'http://localhost:8080/api/example/getUser' from origin 'http://localhost:4200' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
```

For this the backend has the following method in the `UserApi.class`

```
    @GetMapping("{userName:[\\d]+}/getUser")
    public User findUserByName(final @PathVariable String userName) {
        return userService.getUserByName(userName);
    }
```

And in the front `UserService.ts` I have this

```
  getOneUser(userName: string): Observable<User> {
    return this.http().get<User>(`${this.getBaseUrl() + "/" + userName + "/getUser"}`);
  }
```

For the `UserComponent.ts` I did the following

```
export class UserComponent implements OnInit {

  users: User[];
  user: User;

  constructor(private userService: UserService) {
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.userService.getUsers().subscribe((users: User[]) => {
      this.users = users;
    });
  }

  getUserByName(userName: string): void{
    console.log(userName);
    this.userService.getOneUser(userName).subscribe((user: User) => {
      this.user = user;
    });
  }
}
```

As far as I know annotating the
`RestController`
with
`@CrossOrigin(origins = "http://localhost:4200")`
is supposed to take care of the `CORS Policy` but I cannot seem to get past this, is there anything I'm missing?

Comment: Is this example http://localhost:8080/api/example/getUser request url or you have mistake in it?

Answer (score 0):

Okay I found the issue,

in the api the `findByUserName` method

```
@GetMapping("getUser/{userName:[\\d]+}")
public User findUserByName(final @PathVariable("userName") String userName) {
    System.out.println(userName);
    return userService.getUserByName(userName);
}
```

the `[\\d]` was refering to digits only in `@GetMapping("getUser/{userName:[\\d]+}")`

similar to passing an `Integer` but expecting `Long`, I need to find the correct type for this or change the parameter data type